# Terragrunt remote state - get 403 if remote_state block present

Tags: http-status-code-403, terragrunt

my terragrunt.hcl calls a master terragrunt.hcl which contains

```
generate "provider" {
    path = "provider.tf"
    if_exists  = "overwrite_terragrunt"
    contents = <<EOF
  provider "aws" {
  region    = "eu-west-2"
  assume_role {
      role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/${upper(local.account_name)}-CloudSupportAdminRole"
      session_name = "terraform"
  }

}
EOF
}

remote_state {
  backend = "s3" 
    config = {
    role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/terraform-proxy-role"
    bucket         = "terraform-state-main-bucket"
    dynamodb_table = "aweuw2-aws03-dynamodb-terraform-state-lock"
    encrypt        = true
    region         = "eu-west-2"
    key            = "xxx-aws11/environment/toc-dev/iam/terraform.tfstate"
  }
  generate = {
    path  = "remote_state.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
}
```

When I run *terragrunt init* , I get

```
    status code: 403, request id: 253VXGZ93JHVKJFT, host id: +vA7CDCX3M7zUqwyAGhGsR+qCiZX8WCbX/c0wIGXiC5XYcC9A8Pm3CxuoVweN8fh6i3VwbojgWM= 
ERRO[0003] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
```

On checking .terragrunt_cache, the *provider.tf* and *remote_state.tf* are there and if I cd into the folder and run terraform init, it works without error.

Equally (and confusingly), if, once I've run *terragrunt init* and allowed it to create the 2 files, I then remove the remote_state code from *terragrunt.hcl* and run *terragrunt init* again, that works fine too. But if I add the remote_state block back in, it will fail again.

In case it's any use ..

```
terragrunt plan --terragrunt-log-level debug --terragrunt-debug
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions. 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 2 locals (remaining 1): account_details, common_vars 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions. 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 2 locals (remaining 2): account_details, common_vars 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 1): account_name 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_id 
DEBU[0000] [Partial] Included config /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/terragrunt.hcl has strategy shallow merge: merging config in (shallow). 
DEBU[0000] Running command: terraform --version          prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
DEBU[0000] Terraform version: 1.5.0                     
DEBU[0000] Reading Terragrunt config file at /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/terragrunt.hcl 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions. 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 2 locals (remaining 1): account_details, common_vars 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions. 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 2 locals (remaining 2): account_details, common_vars 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 1): account_name 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_id 
DEBU[0000] [Partial] Included config /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/terragrunt.hcl has strategy shallow merge: merging config in (shallow). 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions. 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 2 locals (remaining 1): account_details, common_vars 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions. 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 2 locals (remaining 2): account_details, common_vars 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 1): account_name 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_id 
DEBU[0000] Included config /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/terragrunt.hcl has strategy shallow merge: merging config in (shallow) for dependency. 
DEBU[0000] Detected single bare include block - exposing as top level 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions. 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 2 locals (remaining 2): account_details, common_vars 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 1): account_name 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_id 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions. 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_name  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11] 
DEBU[0000] Found locals block: evaluating the expressions.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): accounts    prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt] 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 2 locals (remaining 2): account_details, common_vars 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 1): account_name 
DEBU[0000] Evaluated 1 locals (remaining 0): account_id 
DEBU[0000] Included config /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/terragrunt.hcl has strategy shallow merge: merging config in (shallow). 
DEBU[0000] Downloading Terraform configurations from git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/SmartDCCAzureSysOps/AWS/dcc_cloud_infra?ref=terragrunt_build into /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/.terragrunt-cache/pbbafWaPne_N3mCsBKJeLecABlU/PDSpjUaMCgNegMR7J2NDd64cA9c 
DEBU[0002] Copying files from /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam into /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/.terragrunt-cache/pbbafWaPne_N3mCsBKJeLecABlU/PDSpjUaMCgNegMR7J2NDd64cA9c/terraform/projects/cedar/iam 
DEBU[0002] Setting working directory to /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/.terragrunt-cache/pbbafWaPne_N3mCsBKJeLecABlU/PDSpjUaMCgNegMR7J2NDd64cA9c/terraform/projects/cedar/iam 
DEBU[0002] Generated file /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/.terragrunt-cache/pbbafWaPne_N3mCsBKJeLecABlU/PDSpjUaMCgNegMR7J2NDd64cA9c/terraform/projects/cedar/iam/provider.tf.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
DEBU[0002] Generated file /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/.terragrunt-cache/pbbafWaPne_N3mCsBKJeLecABlU/PDSpjUaMCgNegMR7J2NDd64cA9c/terraform/projects/cedar/iam/remote_state.tf.  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
INFO[0002] Debug mode requested: generating debug file terragrunt-debug.tfvars.json in working dir /home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/.terragrunt-cache/pbbafWaPne_N3mCsBKJeLecABlU/PDSpjUaMCgNegMR7J2NDd64cA9c/terraform/projects/cedar/iam  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
DEBU[0002] The following variables were detected in the terraform module:  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
DEBU[0002] [tags_owner tags_project tags_service_name tags_environment_name tags_environment_type region profile]  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
DEBU[0002] Variables passed to terraform are located in "/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/terragrunt-debug.tfvars.json"  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
DEBU[0002] Run this command to replicate how terraform was invoked:  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
DEBU[0002]  terraform plan -var-file="/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/terragrunt-debug.tfvars.json" "/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam/.terragrunt-cache/pbbafWaPne_N3mCsBKJeLecABlU/PDSpjUaMCgNegMR7J2NDd64cA9c/terraform/projects/cedar/iam"  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
DEBU[0002] Initializing remote state for the s3 backend  prefix=[/home/julian.berks/git/terragrunt/environments/aws-11/iam] 
ERRO[0003] AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: HFZ24EGFVAE7XYFE, host id: 6xrkMxXN0s3w5VJ7wTJzI7rGlV3WewE3Hz0q2bcZ4qHRvTN2QLd3NycB5XzsBAwCKbbvdJQCgFI= 
ERRO[0003] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
```

Comment: My office laptop insists on using Bing which came up blank. Popped the same issue into Google and immediately came up with https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/1316.
This explains the issue and by adding disable_init = true to the remote_state block it worked. I just need to track down the root cause now.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/1316

The remote_state block does more than just generate the backend configuration. It also informs terragrunt that it should automanage the state bucket (see https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-remote-state-configuration-dry/#create-remote-state-and-locking-resources-automatically). As part of this, terragrunt internally sets up the AWS SDK Go to inspect your AWS account to see if you have the S3 bucket setup correctly. This includes listing the bucket, checking that it has the necessary attributes, updating the bucket access policy to allow the root user, and checking dynamodb for the lock table. This does more than what terraform does during init, which just grabs the state file object, hence there is a difference in the required permissions.

The logs indicate that this is failing in that routine, when terragrunt is running through the checklist of validating if the state bucket is setup correctly, and I was wondering if you may not have the right permissions for modifying that S3 bucket on the user.

If this is ringing any bells, you can disable certain parts of the routine by adding the corresponding skip var to the config (see the docs for more details).

Alternatively, you can completely disable the management feature by setting disable_init to true:

````
    disable_init = true
    backend = "s3"
    generate = {
        path = "backend.tf"
        if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
    }
    config = {
        encrypt = true
        bucket = "<BUCKET>"
        dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-lock-dynamo"
        region = "us-east-1"
        key = "<PATH>/terraform.tfstate"
    }
}```
````